# Why is the "alert" function not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

At the top of my page:

```
<head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="../Home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
        <link href="../Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="../Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="../Scripts/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
```

At the bottom of the page, inside the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                if ($('#chkSelect').is(":checked")) {
                    alert('checked!');
                }
            });
</script>
```

In the middle of the page HTML control:

```
<input id="chkSelect" type="checkbox" />Select All Notifications
```

If I check the checkBox "chkSelect," I want to fire an alert. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you want it to fire as written (when document is ready) then you need this inside the input tag - checked="checked".

Comment: I think you're checking if the checkbox is checked right after the page is loaded. Of course, it's not because you haven't clicked on it yet. You need to use an event to fire the callback on every checkbox change.

Comment: If the script is at the bottom of the page, then why use `.ready()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use an event handler, like `change`.
Your code only runs once, when the page loads, and the checkbox isn't checked.

```
$('#chkSelect').change(function() {
    if( this.checked ) {
        alert('checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: damnit I don't type fast enough :)

Comment: `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(":checked")`

Comment: thanks, this did the trick. I also used what @CrazyTrain mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sanbc/73/)

```
$(function(){
$('#test1').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert('checked');
}
});
```

});

In JAVASCRIPT

```
if (document.getElementById('id').checked){
          alert("checked") ;
  }else{
alert("You didn't check it!")
}
```

Comment: this works but does this work if I want to check whether the check box is checked or not?

Comment: thanks MESSIAH but I'll have to accept Ricardo Lohmann's answer because he provided the right answer first. I'll vote yours up anyway so you get some points :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#chkSelect").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert('checked!');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared an event for the checkbox. Do like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#chkSelect').change(function(){
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        alert('checked!');
                    }
                }
            });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not optimal way to delegate the event towards element with IDentifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically checks for checkbox checked/unchecked when the page loads.

If I'm correct you want to fire a function when checkbox is checked etc.

You can use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) of jQuery.

```
$('#chkSelect').on('click', function() {
    alert('checked');
});
$('#chkSelect').trigger('click');
```